# tableView's commitEditingStyle and knowing when the 'Done' button is tapped

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My controller inherits from UITableViewController with the left button assigned to 'editButtonItem'. How can I find out when the user has tapped the "Done" button after issuing all of the deletes they want?

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

I'm implementing

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

With this, I see when the deletes occur for each item in the table but I would also like to know when the "Done" button is hit.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that I need to override:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

This will tell me when editing has ended.

Comment: Do you need to parent's same method first in your overwrite codes?

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a customized UIBarButtonItem as Edit:

```
editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"
  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleEditing)];
editButton.possibleTitles = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Edit", @"Save", nil];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButton;
isEdit = YES; // class level flag

- (void)toggleEditing {
  if (isEdit) {
    isEdit = NO;
    editButton.text = @"Save";
    ...

  }
  else {
    isEdit = YES;
    editButton.text = @"Save";
    ...
  }
}
```

In this way, you have control of the caption of Edit button and change it to "Save" instead "Done" if you have a Cancel button on the right.